# VisualStudio | Notify if forgotten to declare an Exception in the summary

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I have the following `FooClass`. There are three methods where two of them can throw an `exception`.
If have only declared in the `HasException` method that there can be an `exception` thrown.
When you have large projects it can be possible that you forget to describe the `exceptions` in the summary.

**It is possible to scan the solution if I have forgotten to declare an `exception`? In my example are four `exceptions` (declarations) missing.**

```
public class FooClass
{
    public FooClass()
    {
        HasException();

        HasNoException();

        HasChildException();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method does not throw an <see cref="Exception"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public void HasNoException()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is throwing an <see cref="Exception"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="Exception">Is immediately thrown.</exception>
    public void HasException()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method can throwing an <see cref="Exception"/> from a method it calls.
    /// </summary>
    public void HasChildException()
    {
        //throws an exception
        HasException();

        //throws also an exception
        int.Parse("foo");
    }
}
```

**ToolTips**

[image: hasexception]
[image: parse]

**This should be an example how the method should be described**

```
/// <summary>
/// This method can throwing an <see cref="Exception"/> from a method it calls.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
/// <exception cref="FormatException"></exception>
/// <exception cref="OverflowException"></exception>
public void HasChildException()
{
    //throws an exception
    HasException();

    //throws also an exception
    int.Parse("foo");
}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: Are you able to use Resharper?

Comment: yes I am able to use Resharper

Comment: Use [Roslyn Analyzers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt162308.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for vs 2015>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this (not the only one) is to use Resharper extension named "Exceptional". Go to Resharper > Extension manager > search for "Exceptional", install and restart Visual Studio. After that all places where exception might be thrown which is not documented will be underlined and with alt-enter you will be able to automatically create exception documentation template. For your example it finds all cases you mentioned and even more (constructor itself, which can also throw all thsoe exceptions).

Comment: You're my hero ;) that was **exactly** what I was looking for!!